# How to disable webfonts on Safari only

Tags: css, safari, browser

The webfont I'm using keep crashing on safari, I would like to know if it's possible to disable it only for this browser?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this still works but I have used it in the past:

```
/*\*/
html>body*.safarihack {font-family: "YourFont"; }
/**/
```

But I don't think it's the best way :)